# How to control the stack overflow of my alogrithm in merge sort

Tags: algorithm, c#-4.0, stack-overflow

hi there i still cant find out why my code give me stack overflow its seams that the low and high bound of my merge sort algorithm changing somewhere that should not be done..

```
    int[] arr = new int[10];
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        merge_sort(0, 9);
    }

    private void merge_sort(int left, int right)
    {
        if (left > right)
            merge(left, right, (left + right) / 2);
        else
            merge_sort((left + right) / 2 + 1, right);
        merge_sort(left, (left + right) / 2);

    }
    void merge(int low, int high, int mid)
    {
        int i, j, k, t;
        j = low;
        for (i = mid + 1; i <= high; i++)
        {
            while (arr[j] <= arr[i] && j < i)
                j++;
            if (j == i)
                break;
            t = arr[i];
            for (k = i; k > j; k--)
                arr[k] = arr[k - 1];
            arr[j] = t;
        }
    }
```

Comment: its always cool to see an actual stack overflow problem on here

Comment: From a high level your code doesn't look right. Merge sort typically takes the divide-and-conquer form `merge_sort(left)` then `merge_sort(right)` followed by a call to `merge()`. [Reference here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Comment: you means that first when merge_sort(left) finished the merge() should be run and same for merge_sort(right)!!!

Comment: Please explain what the method should do. give examples of input and outputs so I or We can help you more.

Comment: say it is merge sort, commonly it is array to sort but we use a variable instead of array

Answer (score 1):

Your merge_sort recrusive method will never end since **the last line is always invoked** calling merge_sort again... it's infinite recursive which should cause stackoverflow.

```
private void merge_sort(int left, int right)
{
    if (left > right)
    merge(left, right, (left + right) / 2);
 else
    merge_sort((left + right) / 2 + 1, right);
 merge_sort(left, (left + right) / 2);  //<-- this is your problem!
}
```

I think (maybe) you wanted to do that instead:

```
private void merge_sort(int left, int right)
{
    if (left > right)
    merge(left, right, (left + right) / 2);
 else
 {
    merge_sort((left + right) / 2 + 1, right);
    merge_sort(left, (left + right) / 2)
 }
}
```

Comment: if you always used braces, things would be simpler... a whole pile of style guides recommend always using braces...

Comment: well, it's a matter of flavor.. if you put 3 lines every time you could have 1 line you get longer methods.. I can't say I prefer that..

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
merge_sort((left + right) / 2 + 1, right);
```

which I think should be

```
merge((left + right) / 2 + 1, right);
```

Comment: excuse me can you explain more

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my code like this. the stack overflow problem was solved but i don't get the right result!!!

```
    private void merge_sort(int left, int right)
    {
        if (left > right)
            merge(left, right, (left + right) / 2);
        else
        {
            merge_sort((left + right) / 2 + 1, right);
            merge(left, right, (left + right) / 2+1);

        }

    }
```

Recently i found how to control it by changing part of my code but i still don't understand what was the problem!!!!
here is the changes:

```
    private void merge_sort(int low, int high)
    {

int mid;
        if (low != high)
        {
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
            merge_sort(low, mid);
            merge_sort(mid + 1, high);
            merge(low, mid, high);
        }
```

Comment: Are you missing some curly braces?  Your code indentation __implies__ that the calls to `merge_sort` and `merge` are both in the `else` branch of the `if` statement. Without braces, that final call to `merge` is outside the `if/else`.

Comment: the problem is not only the braces it is more than a simple braces it does not sort the array in fact its seams that the low and high changed somewhere that should not be done.